# Why is there difference between template and auto type deduction for std::initializer_list edge case?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, auto, type-deduction

Basically there are three types of type deduction in C++11:

- templates
- `auto`
- `decltype`

For most cases type deduction of `auto` and templates seems to act in the same way. But there is one case - when we're setting `auto` variable to value produced by brace-enclosed {} initialiser, we get compilation error

```
no match for call to '(std::initializer_list<int>) (<brace-enclosed initializer list>)' foo({0, 1, 2, 3});
```

Here is a link to live sample of the code:
http://ideone.com/ODBAZ5

```
//foo's type would be deduced as std::initializer_list<int>
auto foo = {0, 1, 2, 3}; 

template<typename T> 
void bar(T t){};

//compiles fine
bar( foo );

//next line gives compiler error
bar({0, 1, 2, 3});
```

`decltype` is a whole other story and is beside the point of this question, but `auto` and templates should do the same stuff *(at least that's what seems to be sensible)*, when deducing the type - but they, evidently, don't and it's confusing as to why?

Comment: What compiler error do you get?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I think OP is asking *why* there is a special rule for `auto` but not templates. Why not have `bar()` deduce to `bar<initializer_list<int>>`?

Comment: @Barry - Yes, exactly.

Comment: @NathanOliver - Added compiler error and a link to sample code.